# javascript - onclick do something to the element inside

Tags: javascript, onclick

```
<li onclick='doSomething(this)'><img src='pix.png' /><a href='#'>link</a></li>
<li onclick='doSomething(this)'><img src='pix2.png' /><a href='#'>link2</a></li>
```

Whe the list is click, I wanted the display property of img inside that list become 'inline'

```
function doSomething(obj)
{
    //how to make <img> inside the onclick <li> display=inline
}
```

How to deal with this using that function call,
I want it that way because I have an existing code formatted that way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should do the trick

```
function doSomething(obj)
{
    obj.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.display = "inline";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` on the passed `obj` to find the `img` tags:

```
function doSomething(obj) {
  var images = obj.getElementsByTagName("img");
  for(var i in images) {
    images[i].style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that only one `img` tag exists inside each `li`. Why do you persist to loop so? It just makes extra lines...

Answer (score 0):

Although everyone here will tell you that you shouldn't use inline onclick handlers anymore (and rightly so), I will take it for granted that you have no choice.

You could assign ids to your img elements as such:

```
<li onclick='doSomething("img1")'><img id='img1' src='pix.png' /><a href='#'>link</a></li>
<li onclick='doSomething("img2")'><img id='img2' src='pix2.png' /><a href='#'>link2</a></li>
```

and then:

```
function doSomething(id)
{
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "inline";
}
```